# Heroku: "Domain format is invalid"

Tags: web, heroku

so I tried adding a custom domain to my heroku website, but I've got a "Domain format is invalid" error. My domain looks like name.space, maybe .space isn't an accepted domain?

Answer (score 1):

It's working now, I guess I just had to wait for the verification process, I don't even know what happened, I didn't do anything and it's working.

Comment: For someone reason, I had the same experience. I just waited some time, and it resolved itself.